# How to read data from S3 and render a view every 4 seconds properly?

Tags: javascript, html, express, leaflet

I'm trying to read a file from S3, use the data in that file to render a map on a webpage.

I'm running an Express server along with EJS templating engine to serve/render the webpage.
The file in S3 will get updated every 4 seconds.(As of now, it doesn't).  I need to read the data, put it in the map and render the page every 4 seconds.  Right now, the solution I came up with is not that good. I'm looking for a better method to do this as it throws an error on the first iteration.

Thanks.

main.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var getParams = {
    Bucket: "mapbox-bucket",
    Key: "mobile.json"
};

app.use(express.static('js'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var s3data;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    getS3Data();
    res.render('index', {s3data: s3data});
    setInterval(getS3Data, 2000);
});

function getS3Data(){
    s3.getObject(getParams, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        s3data = JSON.parse(data.Body.toString());
        // console.log(s3data);
    });
}

app.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log("App running on port 8000");
});
```

index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
    <title>Leaflet JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
        crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;"></div>
    <div class="details" style="display: none">
        <div id="lat"><%= s3data.location.lat %></div>
        <div id="lon"><%= s3data.location.lon %></div>
        <div id="IMEI"><%= s3data.IMEI %></div>
        <div id="DeviceName"><%= s3data.DeviceName %></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/map.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

map.js

```js
var lat = document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML;
var lon = document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML;
var imei = document.getElementById('IMEI').innerHTML;
var device = document.getElementById('DeviceName').innerHTML;
// console.log(lat);
// console.log(lon);

var mymap = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 16);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=<My access token>', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
}).addTo(mymap);

var marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(mymap);

var popUpString = "<b>Device Name: " + device + "<br />IMEI: " + imei + "</b>"
marker.bindPopup(popUpString).openPopup();
```

[The error I'm getting when I first load the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Hjt.png)

Comment: What's 'not good' about the solution, and what error does it throw where?

Comment: I've added a link for the screenshot of the error I encounter when loading the page the first time.  The page renders properly when I manually refresh once. The thing about my solution is that I'm sending the data to the view and then reading it in my map.js code.  I couldn't figure out a way to directly send data to map.js from my express code.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting the S3 data repeatedly from the server won't be very helpful. You would still need to initiate a full page refresh from the client every 4 seconds.

It might be easier to handle all this from the client side. Every 4 seconds request the S3 data directly from the browser, and add markers to the map based on the latitude/longitude.

Comment: Right now, I'm using setInterval() to read data from S3 and making the browser refresh every 3 seconds.  How would you suggest I go about requesting data from S3 from the client side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784052/access-files-stored-on-amazon-s3-through-web-browser

Comment: I reckon that instead of refreshing the browser every 4 seconds, I'd be better off using AJAX to refresh the map.  Not completely sure about it though,  is this a good option?

Comment: It's a simple solution to start with. If you still need the server to participate in the data exchange in any way, you could consider connecting to the server with [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) and pushing updates to the client whenever the server sees fit.