# Embedded HTML page from S3 bucket via iframe can't load resources and media files

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iframe

We have an s3 bucket where we have multiple folders with different small projects that contain basic, static webpages with an `index.html` entry point.
The plan is to integrate those static pages within a react-app through an iframe. When we do that with an example page, the embedding of the HTML document works but none of the resources get loaded (image files + stylesheets), throwing the following error:

```
DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "BUCKET-DOMAIN" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

When looking up that error I usually find people trying to control some parts of the document rendered within the iframe using the `postMessage` API. In my case however I only want to make sure that the iframe embeds the website as it is shown on the publically available link with all resources.

I've tried making the S3 bucket specifically serve just one static website, thinking that this might influence the way the embedding works. However it's still the same problem.
Pretty sure there's a very simple solution to this and something I'm overlooking.
One potential option would be to give the S3 bucket a subdomain on our site, but I don't see how that would work for example in local development.

Comment: Did your bucket is public ?

Answer (score 0):

If you bucket is public then you can access with your cdn link . Otherwise You will configure it with aws sdk. I think this link will help you

[Access files stored on Amazon S3 through web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784052/access-files-stored-on-amazon-s3-through-web-browser)

Comment: Yes, all the files are publically available. Can easily access the site outside of the iframe and even within the iframe it gets rendered correctly, except for the resources (stylesheets + media)

Comment: Below this document you can find cdn link and show your image .

https://havecamerawilltravel.com/how-allow-public-access-amazon-bucket/

If it is not helpful ,please comment here.

Comment: Sorry Khandker, I'm not sure whether you've understood the problem I'm facing. All the files in the bucket are already publically available and you can easily access the site I'm trying to embed via the public link.
The problem is that when I embed the site using an iframe tag, the iframe makes a request from my page to another domain (cross-site domain), which is not allowed. I'm trying to get around that, because it's explicitly what I want the iframe to do.

Comment: Oh I am really sorry for waste your time . I didn't undersatnd .

Comment: No worries at all! Thanks a lot for trying to help!