# Are there open source tools that extract Junit test results etc from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, junit, jenkins-plugins

I have some test results from Junit, that I can't keep on my Jenkins run and need to be pushed to AWS S3 location. Now on S3 the files exist and one has to download each file individually to a folder to see the results which is painful.
I was wondering if there are any open source tools who right now can do this task of taking some htmls/xmls from AWS S3 to display in pretty nice charts?

Comment: An HTML report can be generated by JUnit. It sounds like you are already doing that though. If you have the HTML files on S3 then why do you have to "download each file"? Why not just configure the S3 bucket to serve the files as a static website?

Comment: @Mark, good idea but due to security can't do that.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15633672/4296747

Comment: Nice post Henri, seems going for s3 as website as a viable solution but due to securities/permission around S3 buckets is not I can tamper with. In short I am looking for S3Brower type stuff [as we can use it in local ], which has the capability to display the bucket listing in html pages. Like I am opening my surefire reports.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

End up writing a Java Util, that will basically post the "Test Case Class, Methods, Expected test values, Obtained test values, I/P Values used, Expected Result of asserts"

[Html Reporting Asserts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNuMS.png)