# S3 allow public directory listing of parent folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have public permissions for one of my S3 buckets like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1493660686651",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1493660682556",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::polodata/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

When a user navigates to a specific file like: `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/polodata/ETHBTC.csv`, it prompts the user to download -- which is fine. However, when they navigate to: `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/polodata/` (without the file specified), it returns an XML page.

What do I need to change so that the latter returns a directory listing page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get a **directory listing page** out of Amazon S3 when accessing the URL. The closest is the XML list of objects, for which you must grant `ListObjects` permission on the bucket policy. It looks like this:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <Name>my-bucket</Name>
  <Prefix/>
  <Marker/>
  <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
  <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
  <Contents>
    <Key>foo.txt</Key>
    <LastModified>2017-05-01T21:07:13.000Z</LastModified>
    <ETag>"9311482f31be49fb2f41be9e16097a9c"</ETag>
    <Size>213</Size>
    <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
  </Contents>
  <Contents>
    <Key>my-folder/</Key>
    <LastModified>2017-05-01T21:07:18.000Z</LastModified>
    <ETag>"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"</ETag>
    <Size>0</Size>
    <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
  </Contents>
  <Contents>
    <Key>my-folder/bar.txt</Key>
    <LastModified>2017-05-01T21:07:30.000Z</LastModified>
    <ETag>"9311482f31be49fb2f41be9e16097a9c"</ETag>
    <Size>213</Size>
    <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
  </Contents>
</ListBucketResult>
```

Some people have come up with creative ways of *simulating* a directory listing, eg: [Directory Listing in S3 Static Website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9253512/174777)

Remember -- Amazon S3 isn't a traditional web server. It's an **object storage service** that can also serve content to the Internet. So, it won't behave exactly the same as a normal web server.

See also: [How Do I Configure an S3 Bucket for Static Website Hosting?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html)