# Nginx to serve downloadable S3 files

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, file-browser

I want to serve downloadable files from S3 through Nginx to internal people.

I tried `rufuspollock/s3-bucket-listing`, which worked perfectly. But it need bucket to be public. I don't want to make bucket public.

Is there any other way to do this possible ?

Comment: Tried setting the `autoindex on` *inside* the `location / {}` block?

Comment: already tried that, no change in output.

Comment: So you want to do this without downloading the files?

Comment: I want to download it through Nginx.

Comment: @roy, any update on this?

Comment: Nope, I manage to do it by mounting the s3 bucket on EC2 and serving those files via Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work the way you expect. Reason being the endpoints will return XML, so what you need is a web interface which then interfaces with S3 and provides you a folder like interface.

Below thread has a lot of interesting options you can explore

[Directory Listing in S3 Static Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253512/directory-listing-in-s3-static-website)

Comment: This required bucket to be public. I want to use private bucket to server downloaded files to internal people.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/powdahound/s3browser/. Looking at the config it supports private buckets